# unable to read large bz2 file

Tags: python

I am trying to read a large bz2 file with this code:

```
import bz2
file= bz2.BZ2File("20150219.csv.bz2","rb")
print file.read()
file.close()
```

But after 4525 lines, it stops without an error message. The bz2 file is much bigger.
How can I read the whole file line by line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `file.read()` call tries to read the entire file into memory and then and decompress all of it there, too. Try reading it a line at a time:

```
import bz2

with bz2.BZ2File("20150219.csv.bz2", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
```

Comment: thanks for the replay .. i tried as you suggested, still i can only access 4245 lines. The compressed file has around 7 lac lines is that a problem? can i specify size for a file ?

Comment: I don't know what "lac lines" means, nor of a way to specify a size for the file. Have you tried uncompressing the file with some other utility...perhaps it's corrupt. You could also try using the third-party [bz2file](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bz2file) module.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to print a binary file line by line? Read them to a bytes object instead:

```
bs = file.read()
```